# How to use mod_authn_dbd with SQL Server (ODBC)

Tags: sql-server, apache, authentication, odbc

There are many tutorial for using [mod_authn_dbd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) with MySQL but I could not find any with SQL Server using ODBC. It took me a while to figure it out, so I decided to write it up here. It's not a full blown tutorial but it should be enough to get you up and running.

Answer (score 1):

All commands must be run as root or using sudo.

**Install Microsoft ODBC drivers for Linux**

[Instructions on Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Example for Debian 9:

```
apt update
apt install curl apt-transport-https

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

**Configure /etc/odbc.ini**

Example content:

```
[DBSERVER1]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server = 192.168.1.123
```

**Install and enable mod_authn_dbd**

```
apt install libaprutil1-dbd-odbc
a2enmod dbd
a2enmod authn_dbd
a2enmod authn_socache
```

**Configure Apache authentication**

Add this somewhere in your site config:

```
DBDriver odbc
DBDParams "DATASOURCE=DBSERVER1,USER=dbuser,PASSWORD=dbpass"

<Location "/test">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Secured area"
        AuthBasicProvider socache dbd

        AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
        AuthnCacheContext my-server

        Require valid-user

        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT USR_PASS FROM USERS WHERE USR_EMAIL=%s"
</Location>
```