# Apache DBD authn ODBC MSSQL is not working

Tags: sql-server, apache, odbc

I'm following this question ([How to use mod_authn_dbd with SQL Server (ODBC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797009/how-to-use-mod-authn-dbd-with-sql-server-odbc)) to configure Apache 2.4 (On debian 9 up-to-date) to authenticate my user on a MS-SQL Database.

My Goal is to protect an OCSInventory Server.
In the z-ocsinventory-server.conf, I add :

```
DBDriver odbc
DBDParams "DATASOURCE=ODBCSRV,USER=ocs,PASSWORD=ocspwd"

DBDMin 4
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax 20
DBDExptime 300
```

In the section "Location /ocsinventory"

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "OCS Inventory agent area"
# AuthBasicProvider socache dbd
AuthBasicProvider dbd
# AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
# AuthnCacheContext my-server
AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT Password as password FROM OCS WHERE login=%s"
# AuthBasicProvider    file
# AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/htpasswd.users"
require valid-user
```

In the odbc.ini

```
[ODBCSRV]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server = ipserver
```

Trying to access to the database with isql is perfectly working. Execute the query work also.

The return password from the request in AuthDBDUserPWQuery is prefixed with {SHA} but it's not working. Apache Log appear 'Password Mismatch'.

Same user/password in a htpasswd file is working. So I think the issue is the ODBC configuration. Some adjustement in the SQL statement return "normal" error. Per example: call an non existing user, apache log show "user not found". - specify a non existing column, apache log an error "column not found".

I'm trying also to trim() the password but no effect.

Any suggestion could be appreciate to help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you show the relevant apache config? Especially the AuthDBDUserPWQuery query.

Comment: You can run "htpasswd -nbs user password" on the linux command line to check that your password is encoded correctly.

Comment: @GuillaumeFilion question edited to anwser your comments.